# Node.js: JSON.parse() error when strings are too long

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using Node to request API and parse the returned JSON. When I requests an API for several times, node crashes and reports a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` error. The error is located at a character in a string of the JSON object. I found that the string is very long (60000+ characters encoded with utf-8). Is this problem caused by the too long string? How does it happens?

JSON string can see here: 
http://www.liyan93.com/mdnotes/JinquanquanIssues/errorData.json

Comment: This parsed for me with no problem.

Comment: This string isn't terribly long. I've dealt with strings 10x this file. Perhaps the unicode is being an issue for you.

Comment: @TomDDD Seems you're right. But why will this problem happen after several times instead of every time?

Answer (score 2):

```js
https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
      const jsonDATA = JSON.parse(data).parse;

      var jsonText = jsonDATA.text;

      console.log(jsonText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this when the connection was terminated by the other side / cut off before the full string was transferred. Perhaps that could be the cause?

Tip: The latest Node provides a little more useful error upon json parse error, showing a part of the string. You can also use `jju` as the parser, it provides even a better error message.